# Algorithm for board game and heap problems

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, out-of-memory

I'm developing an algorithm to play the Lines of action board game.

The software (in java) builds a tree with all the pawns possible moves on the board. Each level of the tree is filled with the possible moves of a turn :

level 0 : The first move played by the opponent
level 1 : The possible moves I can play
level 2 : The possible moves the opponent can play after my first move
... And so on.

In the lines of action game, each player starts with 12 pawns which can do one move in a maximum of 8 directions, so the maximal number of possible moves for 1 turn is 96. Which means each level of the tree is populated by 96^depth move nodes.

Now when I compute the possible moves tree for a max depth of 4, the software should use 
84 934 656 (96^4) times a treeNode object's required memory of space on the RAM right? To be clearer, if a treeNode object occupies 10 bytes, then a level 4 tree should use ~ 850 MB.

Here's my node class, I tried to make it use very low memory with only 3 instance attributes : `public class MinNode {

```
public static int myColor;

public final MaxNode[] childNodes = new MaxNode[mainClass.NB_POSSIBLE_MOVES];

private byte nbChildren = 0;

public final byte startIndex;
public final byte endIndex;

public MinNode(final int[] currentBoard, final byte startIndex, final byte endIndex, final int depth){
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
    this.endIndex = endIndex;

    if (depth <= mainClass.MAX_DEPTH){

        computeMyPossibleMoves(currentBoard, depth);
    }
}

private void computeMyPossibleMoves(final int[] currentBoard, final int depth){...}

// Only if move is valid
private void addMove(final int[] currentBoard, final byte startIndex, final byte endIndex, final int depth){

    int buffer = currentBoard[endIndex];
    currentBoard[endIndex] = currentBoard[startIndex];
    currentBoard[startIndex] = mainClass.NO_PAWN;

    childNodes[nbChildren++] = new MaxNode(currentBoard, startIndex, endIndex, depth + 1);

    currentBoard[startIndex] = currentBoard[endIndex];
    currentBoard[endIndex] = buffer;
}`
```

I initialize the tree building by calling the constructor with the move just played by the opponent. MaxNodes and MinNodes are the same basically, I just differentiated them for the minimax algorithm that will parse the tree.

My question is : How can I reach higher depth levels without getting *out of memory* errors?

Comment: @MrLore : I'm not storing the board anywhere... I always pass it as a parameter in the methods. I only have 1 board stored. Which is a 1D array btw. The x, y you're referring to is the startIndex and endIndex attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the whole tree up front, you just need to dynamically create the children as you're running the minimax algorithm.

You also need to make sure you're running minimax in a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) manner (as opposed to [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)), but this is likely already the case.

This should require storing no more than `depth * branchingFactor` or `depth` nodes (depending on the implementation) at any given time.

Comment: I'm not parsing the tree (or searching), i'm building it, but it's branching factor is so big that after 4 levels it's too big and occupies too much memory.

Comment: Don't build the whole tree then, just dynamically create it as you're doing the DFS.